# How make bootstrap datetimepicker to select only time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Using bootstrap datetimepicker with init like :

```
  $('#departure-time').datetimepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
  }).on('change', function () {
  });
```

I did not find how can I make to select only time
Setting format :

```
format: 'hh:ii'
```

Did not help.

Which way is correct ?

I have :

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
"bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
"bootstrap-datetime-picker": "^2.4.4",
"bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^0.0.7",
```

**MODIFIED  :**
In my project "jquery": "^3.3.1" is used and I can not move to "jquery 2,
Can it be reason of

```
“Uncaught Error: Invalid date format.    at Object.parseFormat” error
```

in console when I init 
Datetimepicker as :

```
$('#time_utc').datetimepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'LT',
}).on('change', function () {
});
```

Can I fix the error ?

**MODIFIED # 2:**
I try to raise bootstrap-datetimepicker to version 4.17.47,  which seems latest at 
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

But I have problems with it, as
In package.json of my project I have line:

```
  "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^0.0.7",
```

I modified it to

```
  "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
```

But running npm install I got error:

```
      npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap-datetimepicker@^4.17.47.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I modified it to

```
"bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
```

But running npm install I got similar error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I cleared bootstrap-datetimepicker from package.json

and run

```
npm install  bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

on installation I again see in package.json:

```
"bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.7",
```

What I have from the start.

Also, please take a look at package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "cleanup": "rm -rf public/assets public/css public/fonts public/images public/js public/mix-manifest.json ",
        "predev": "npm run cleanup",
        "dev": "npm run fix && npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run fix && npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "lint": "npx standard 'resources/js/**/*.js'",
        "fix": "npx standard 'resources/js/**/*.js' --fix"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^11.2.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "^12.4.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block": "^12.4.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^12.4.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "^12.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/google-calendar": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
        "@uppy/core": "^1.8.2",
        "@uppy/progress-bar": "^1.3.7",
        "@uppy/tus": "^1.5.5",
        "@yaireo/tagify": "^2.23.1",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "autosize": "^4.0.0",
        "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
        "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
        "bootstrap-datetime-picker": "^2.4.4",
        "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.7",
        "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
        "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
        "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
        "bootstrap-select": "1.13.10",
        "bootstrap-switch": "3.3.4",
        "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
        "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.2.5",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
        "corejs-typeahead": "^1.3.0",
        "counterup": "^1.0.2",
        "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.4",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.6.0",
        "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.2",
        "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.3.0",
        "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.6",
        "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.5.1",
        "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
        "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.1.1",
        "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.2.6",
        "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.0.1",
        "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.3.1",
        "dompurify": "^1.0.9",
        "dropzone": "^5.7.0",
        "dual-listbox": "1.1.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "es6-promise-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
        "flot": "^3.2.2",
        "gmaps": "^0.4.25",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.3",
        "inputmask": "^4.0.6",
        "ion-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
        "jkanban": "^1.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-form": "^4.2.2",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "jquery-validation": "1.19.0",
        "jquery.repeater": "^1.2.1",
        "jqvmap": "^1.5.1",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
        "jstree": "^3.3.9",
        "jszip": "^3.2.2",
        "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
        "markdown": "^0.5.0",
        "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
        "nouislider": "^13.1.0",
        "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
        "pace": "0.0.4",
        "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
        "pdfmake": "^0.1.65",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "prismjs": "^1.8.4",
        "quill": "^1.3.6",
        "raphael": "^2.2.7",
        "select2": "^4.0.13",
        "socicon": "^3.0.5",
        "sticky-js": "^1.2.0",
        "stream-exhaust": "^1.0.2",
        "summernote": "^0.8.16",
        "sweetalert2": "^8.0.6",
        "tagify": "^0.1.1",
        "tether": "^1.4.3",
        "tinymce": "^5.2.0",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "tooltip.js": "^1.2.0",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3",
        "uppy": "^1.10.1",
        "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
        "wnumb": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.3",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "standard": "^14.3.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "standard": {
        "globals": [
            "$",
            "jQuery",
            "_",
            "moment",
            "turf",
            "swal",
            "toastr",
            "axios",
            "L",
            "FormData",
            "KTUtil",
            "KTApp"
        ]
    }
}
```

It has alot of packages. This project is not mine, I just joined to the team.
Can reason of the error be errors in this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `format: 'LT'`, check the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#time-only):

```
$('#departure-time').datetimepicker({
  // todayHighlight: true,
  // autoclose: true,
  format: 'LT'
}).on('change', function () {
});
```

**Update**

Working example (jQuery 2.x, Bootstrap 3):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#departure-time').datetimepicker({
    // todayHighlight: true,
    // autoclose: true,
    format: 'LT'
  }).on('change', function() {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='departure-time'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used jQuery version 2.x because of this [bug](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1714).

**Update 2**

Here's another working example using

> jQuery 3.3.1
>
> Bootstrap 4.4.1
>
> Bootstrap-datetimepicker 4.17.47

The Glyphicons removed in Bootstrap 4, so I included them from Bootstrap 3.

The bootstrap-datetimepicker you use is very old, you should update it to a newer version.

Use `npm update` or `npm update bootstrap-datetimepicker` or `bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47` for a specific version or you can change it in the `package.json` file.

If the version not changed, you can try to remove the file `package-lock.json` (save a copy of it) and modify the version in your `package.json` and run `npm install`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#departure-time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
  }).on('change', function() {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='departure-time'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and I gor error in console : app.js:9976 Uncaught Error: Invalid date format.
    at Object.parseFormat (app.js:9976)
    at new Datetimepicker (app.js:8491)       No default value? Did I miss some options

Comment: if remove  todayHighlight and  autoclose props I have the same error

Comment: if remove  todayHighlight and  autoclose props I have the same error in the console

Comment: Try to place your bootstrap js file after jquery and before all js files.

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED

Comment: Remove `todayHighlight` and `autoclose` from the options as I answered before.

Comment: Sure , I removed these options - but the same error

Comment: That is Laravel 6 app and in In package.json I have :
          
         "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-form": "^4.2.2",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "jquery-validation": "1.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
        "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
        "bootstrap-datetime-picker": "^2.4.4",
        "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^0.0.7",    Seems I have very low version of bootstrap-datetimepicke ?  Can it be issue of the error in console

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED # 2,

Comment: Also, I payed attention at 4 datepickers in package.json. But which of them is corresponding to this https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#time-only which I have to iuse and looks like I have to remove the rest ?

Comment: You can try to remove the file `package-lock.json` (save a copy of it) and modify the version in your `package.json` and run `npm install`